# Proving there is no set of five distinct points s.t. every three points are the vertices of a right triangle.

Tags: geometry, triangles

We can see that the following proposition is true.

**Proposition** : Each triangle $ABD, ACD, BCD$ is a right triangle for 
$$A(0,b,0), B(a,0,0), C(0,0,0)\ \ \ (a\gt 0, b\gt 0)$$
$\iff D$ is either $(a,b,0)\ \text{or}\ (a,0,p)\ \text{or}\ (0,b,p)\ \text{or}\ (q,0,r)\ \text{or}\ (0,s,t)$
where $$p\not=0, q^2+r^2=qa, 0\lt q\lt a, s^2+t^2=sb, 0\lt s\lt b.$$

Using this proposition enables us to show the following theorem.

**Theorem** : There is no set of five distinct points within three-dimensional space such that every set of three points of them are the vertices of a right triangle.

Then, here is my question.

> **Question** : Can you show the theorem without using the proposition?

Comment: Yes. Once three points have been chosen, they determine the fourth. This is not difficult to convince yourself of.

Comment: @user18063: I think what you are saying is the same as using the proposition. Can you explain it more?

Comment: Why should you want to prove this another way? Just curiosity, or is there an application behind this?

Comment: @MvG: Just curiosity. The reason why I'm asking this question is to know 'better' ways to show the theorem because using the proposition is all I've found. In my opinion, using the proposition is not very 'beautiful', so I'm expecting to see 'better' ideas.